# findViewById() returns null even in the right layout

Tags: android

I also read other topics, but none of them proved successful

I am trying to add a simple `Checkbox` on a layout in Android, called `activity_main.xml`

My code looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void submitOrder(View view) {
    CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_checkbox);
    boolean hasWhippedCream = whippedCreamCheckBox.isChecked();
    String orderMessage = createOrderMessage(quantity, hasWhippedCream);

    submitOrder(orderMessage);
}
```

Whatever I do, `whippedCreamCheckBox` is `null`.

My `XML` file looks like this

```
<!-- This is the activity_main.xml -->
<!-- Checkbox for WHIPPED_CREAM -->
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/whipped_cream_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Whipped Cream"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:padding="16dp"/>
```

So far I've tried:

- cleaning the project ( `Build` -> `Clean`, read about it here )
- renaming the Checkbox (it appears at suggestions)

My error looks like this:

```
09-20 16:33:27.599 3656-3656/com.example.android.justjava 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.android.justjava, PID: 3656

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
```

Comment: What you want to do with `submitOrder(orderMessage);` ?

Comment: It's simply updating the `TextView`'s text. @Nilesh Rathod submited the right answer, but I'm not able to accept it yet.

Comment: Okey. Best of luck and keep coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to find the `checkbox` as a child of whatever view is being clicked. Your `checkbox` is not a child of the clicked view, therefore you need to find it as a child of your activity/fragment.

**use this**

```
CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_checkbox);
```

**instead of this**

```
CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_checkbox);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here in this line of code remove `view`

```
CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_checkbox);
```